# Whether Page Border Options are available in Libre Office Writer 5?

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

I Could see the Page Border Option in Microsoft-Word but not in Libre Office Writer-5 which is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 's default one !!!

Is there any options are available regarding to that in Libre Office Writer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose Format -> Page -> Borders.

See [this](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Defining_Borders_for_Pages) for further help.